# Exam (not exam class) with LaTeX

Tags: numbering

I would like to do an exam with LaTeX. I want to use the `srcartcl` class and the exam itself is ready. But I like to have a number as a unique identifier for the students. So, for 60 students, I like to have written 01, 02, 03, ... up to 60 at a defined position in the document. The rest of course stays unchanged. Is that somehow achievable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably help to have a better idea of how you're formatting your exam.  But I'll give it a go.
I teach in an extremely crowded classroom.  So, when I administer exams and quizzes, I use multiple versions of the quiz.  This *can* be a pain in the neck to write.  But there are ways to streamline the process.

First, I separate the preamble and LaTeX command definitions from the body of the document.  So the **master file** I process through LaTeX is very plain looking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
\input{quizbody}
\end{document}
```

I can then issue a versioning command and repeated input the quiz as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}

\setversion{a}
\input{quizbody}
\clearpage

\setversion{b}
\input{quizbody}
\clearpage

\setversion{c}
\input{quizbody}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

The mechanics of this are a bit more complicated than you probably need for your document.  This is where knowing something a bit more about how you implement your exam could be useful.  But here are some basics:

Here's an example:

**The preamble:** filehandle *preamble.tex*

This is where I load all packages and where I define all counters and commands that I will use throughout the document.

```
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%% student specific commands
\newcounter{studentidcounter}
\setcounter{studentidcounter}{1}
\newcommand{\studentid}{\thestudentidcounter}
%% formatting the header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{Student ID: \texttt{\large\studentid}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%% formatting for quiz questions
\newcounter{quizproblemcounter}
\newcommand{\quizproblem}{\vspace{2ex}\par\stepcounter{quizproblemcounter}%
                          \noindent\textbf{\sffamily QP\thequizproblemcounter.}%
                          \hspace*{1em}}
```

**The quiz file:** filehandle: *quizbody.tex*

This is the content of the document.  No new commands are defined here.  No new counters are defined.

```
\quizproblem \lipsum[1]

\quizproblem \lipsum[2]

\quizproblem \lipsum[3]

\quizproblem \lipsum[4]

\quizproblem \lipsum[5]

\quizproblem \lipsum[6]

\quizproblem \lipsum[7]

\quizproblem \lipsum[8]

\quizproblem \lipsum[9]
```

**The master document:**  filehandle--your call

Here I just input the various files that I'll need and only execute actions necessary between formatting the next version of the quiz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}

\multido{\nx=1+1}{60}{  
    \input{quizbody}    
    \clearpage
    \stepcounter{studentidcounter}%
    \setcounter{page}{1}%
    \setcounter{quizproblemcounter}{0}%
}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

To reformat the student id:

```
\newcommand{\studentid}{%
        \ifnum\thestudentidcounter<10\relax%
        0\thestudentidcounter\else%
        \thestudentidcounter\fi}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! But two additional questions: Can I somehow force a blank page if the quizbody has an odd number of pages? This would be nice to have when printing two sided. And question two: Can I force the numbers to have the format 01, 02, etc instead of 1, 2, ...?

Comment: 1) `\cleardoublepage{}`

Comment: Your first *additional* question has been answer in someone else's comment.  I've added an **edit** above to show how to get the numbering of ids as you would like.